disconnect packages managed by alpine apk but keep them on the system
I've installed nextcloud on proxmox in an alpine container using ttecks (rip!) helper script. After some tweaks, I am now able to update nextcloud from the application itself.
Now I have the following issue: Nextcloud is still managed by alpines apk, so when I run apk upgrade, the nextcloud package will be updated too, what will break my nextcloud instance.
Is there a way to remove (the nextcloud) packages from the management by apk? Like removal of the apk database? I tried to remove it from the /etc/apk/world file. The result is nextcloud beeing removed by apk :/
